# 100 Usernames to search for in SQL

Tags: sql

I need to perform a query on a large database with thousands of users.  I have the query except I need to search where username = 600 different usernames.  How do I do such a thing without having to paste all of the usernames and manually format each name?

Comment: Hi, Dizzelk.  We would need more details to answer this question.  What is the query you've written so far?  Where are these 600 names stored?  If in another table, is there a flag on the other table that will narrow the list down to these 600?
Or perhaps there's a pattern in the names themselves that's unique to the 600 that we can exploit?

Comment: It is a canned report.  I can filter by one username, or 10 usernames using "where" clause, but how do I filter by 600 without having to paste a list of them into the query?

Comment: You have two choices. Either use the [SQL] [IN](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp) operator or perform a [sub-] query that returns the _600 different usernames_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per @Abra's comment. There are a few options:

*Using the SQL* `IN` *Operator with a list of values:*

```
SELECT *
FROM someTable t
WHERE t.userName IN ('userName1', 'username2', ...)
```

This option means formatting all possible values to be within quotes and separated by comma's, which can be a chore when dealing with many values. There are some tricks to make this easier (at least in SQL Server). For example you can hold shift + alt and press the arrow keys to select and format multiple rows at the same time.

*Using the* `IN` *operator with a subquery:*

This is a more convenient option when dealing with lots of possible values:

```
SELECT *
FROM someTable t
WHERE t.userName IN 
(
    SELECT u.username 
    FROM users u 
    WHERE u.someColumn = 'someValue'
)
```

This will only work though when you can filter the users adequately using the where clause.

When a link can be established between the tables, a `JOIN` might be a good option:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM someTable t
JOIN users u ON u.userId = t.userId
WHERE u.someColumn = 'someValue')
```

Answer (score 0):

I did indeed have to use the "IN" operator.  This site saved me hours in formatting.
[SQL Auto Formatter](https://www.dpriver.com/pp/sqlformat.htm)